# What video codex works best to encode Pixel Art-like videos?

Tags: video, pixel, video-encoding

I would like to encode a video with some pixel-art-like graphics.
However, I cannot find a codex + a configuration that does not make the pixel-art look very bad:

The best codex I found so far is F4V with some very high quality settings. However, it makes the corners of the "drawn pixels" "round". (The "drawn pixels" are supposed to be perfect squares).

This picture shows on the left what I would like to get, and on the right what I get.
The picture shows a small part of the screen -- and it has been enlarged 200% to emphasis the problem.

Any idea of what codex to use?

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: Is this like a training video on editing bitmaps where you would **want** to see the pixels to show how to pixel-edit?

Comment: Nop :) It is a trailer for a video game I am making: http://buildanddefend.com/

Comment: well, the right side actually looks better to me.  Why are you concerned about the codec making the pixels 'round'?  Typically this is an optical illusion to reduce the image sizes without changing the users optical perception.  Are you sure you don't want this?

Answer (score 0):

First, its codec not codex. Second F4V is not a codec, it is a [container](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_container_format).

Video encoding is always a trade off. Currently, h.264 is almost always "best". Using x264 you can encode lossless (--qp 0). But this may give you very large files. As you reduce the bitrate or quantizer mode, you are going to lose quality. But there are other tuning options.

I suspect your biggest issue is the loop filter. Video codecs split each frame into smaller squares (blocks), and encode each one separately. When displayed, you then get a "screen door" effect where the block edges are easily visible. To handle this, many codecs then blur along the block edges to try to hide the boundary. This is called deblocking. In h.264 this is performed by the loop filter. You can tune the loop filter with --deblock option.

Here is an image I found that demonstrates: http://content.ll-0.com/kin2/word_images/4860472_image016.jpg

There are [many many](http://mewiki.project357.com/wiki/X264_Settings) other options you can tune as well.

Good Luck

Answer (score 0):

Animation codec:

http://www.siggraph.org/education/materials/HyperGraph/video/codecs/Animation.html

Whether you can find an appropriate way to use this in open-source or other environment is questionable at best.

Other than that, I would almost suggest a series of GIFs.  GIFs use only very basic, but possibly effective, RunLength Encoding image compression.

Any codec that uses a JPG base, which AFAIK is all of them, is going to introduce undesirable effects for non-photo-realistic images.